# how to handle a mathematical function in C language like MATLAB

Tags: c, matlab

I'm looking for a way to create a "variable-function" in C language.
In MATLAB i'm able to create something like:

`my_function = (@x) sin(x) + x^2 + x;`

so that i'm able to evaluate it for any value of 'x' i like:

`my_point = 3.09;
my_function(my_point);`

is there anything like that for C language?

Comment: Just a regular function.

Comment: are you looking for function pointers? See this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51924748/4612

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: I don't think the OP is interested in function pointers. Looks like thy are just looking for shortcuts.

Comment: What do you mean by "variable function"? Do you want to use plain text that is entered during runtime and holds the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a regular C function. The terminology would be: "A function with arguments"

```
double my_function(double x)
{
  return sin(x) + x*x + x;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define my_function(x) sin(x) + pow(x,2) + x
int main()
{
    double my_point = 3.09;
    printf("%lf",my_function(my_point));
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: But if you now do `my_function(my_point+1)` you get the wrong answer!

Comment: use #define my_function(x) sin(x) + pow(x,2) + x then you get the right answer.

Comment: The correct way to define macros in C is to add lots of parenthesis everywhere. Your updated macro still doesn't do the right thing for `my_function(x>>2)`, for example (bitshift `>>` has lower precendence than `+`). And you need to add some around the full expression as well, as `2 * my_function(my_point)` doesn't produce the right answer either. Correct is something like `#define my_function(x) (sin(x) + (x)*(x) + (x))`. You can't have too many parenthesis in a macro, there's always unexpected inputs...

Comment: Why would a preprocessor macro be appropriate here instead of just a regular function that takes a parameter?